# Swift converting JSON to dictionary array issues Error Code 3840 (Garbage at end)

Tags: json, swift, jsonserializer

Throughout HTML requests I download a JSON file from my database. This is the JSON file I get back.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e8e09d0bf75d176ecfa2101"},"name":"Pasta al pomodoro","category":"Primi","ingredients":"","price":"15.99","available":true}{"_id":{"$oid":"5e8e0c2da73abb76ec812daf"},"name":"Cotoletta","category":"Carne","ingredients":"Cotoletta, Limone","price":"25.99","available":true}
```

I try converting the JSON file into a dictionary array so that I can select items by doing as an example:

```
myArray[0]['name']
```

This is the code I use to try and convert the JSON:

```
do {
    let myArray = try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .mutableContainers) as? [Dictionary<String, Any>])!
    print(myArray)
    //completion(myArray, nil)
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work; it returns the error message:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Comment: try removing the options parameter from your jsonSerilization]

Comment: already tried, didn't work.

Comment: You cannot *convert* a dictionary to an array with `JSONSerialization` and the JSON seems to be a dictionary. And `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift anyway.

Comment: So how would you solve the issue?

Comment: somethings wrong with your JSON, inputting your response into a formatter gives error . https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Does it specify what is wrong?

Comment: It's two dictionary, but there should be an array of dictionary. Your JSON is missing that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the PHP server, as it did not issue the JSON file correctly. To fix it I had to make sure the PHP file echoed a "[" before the first DB row, include a "," between each DB row and end the file with a "]".

Before:

```
foreach ($rows as $document) {
        echo(json_encode($document));
    }
```

After:

```
echo "[";
foreach ($rows as $document) {
    echo(json_encode($document));
    echo (", ");
}
echo "]";
```